# Multiple gradle versions

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have a java project in Visual Studio Code with some subprojects:

```
javaProject
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
├── chronos
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   ├── src
├── crate-generator-strategy
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── dafne
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
├── gradle.properties
├── hermes
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   ├── src
├── meti
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
└── settings.gradle
```

Under the main dir `javaProject` there's a dir called `.gradle` and in that I have different versions of gradle (i.e. 6.4, 7.1.1, 7.4.1)

In my system I have only the 7.4.1 version installed.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-09 15:04:47 UTC
Revision:     36dc52588e09b4b72f2010bc07599e0ee0434e2e

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.2 (Homebrew 17.0.2+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.1 x86_64
```

If I delete the dir, it suddenly reappear with all the versions.

Why there are many versions and not the installed one?

How could I get rid of the old ones?

Thanks,

S.

Comment: Can you please check that your subprojects have the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file? If yes, please check Gradle versions in all prop files.

Comment: no, I don't have any of those files, I have added the Gradle Version in the "Java › Import › Gradle: Version" preference of VSC. It works.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of your project structure?